# How to sort documents returned by a Mongodb database?

Tags: angular, mongodb

I am using Angular 11 and nodeJs. My nodeJs code return documents. I would like to documents to be listed randomly(without considering thier posting period).

Here is my nodeJs code

```
function getAllUsers(req, res){
    Users.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.json(result);
        }
      }); 
}
```

My angular code

```
/* 
    in this code:
       _http: is an instance of HttpClient
       this.users: is a declared variable in this component

e.g: the "getUsersForDataSorting" methode is called in the ngInit() method.

*/
getUsersForDataSorting(){
  return this._http.get<any[]>(this.url + 'getUsersForSorting').subscribe(
      (users)=>{
          this.users=users;
          
                   
           } 
  ); 
}
```

These codes above lists documents from the most recents one to the oldest one, based on the createdAt field.

My question is How to list documents randomly? Thank you in advance

Comment: it returns items as they are stored in the database. is there any particular goal you are trying to achieve by this randomness?

Comment: yes I am working on a photo-based online voting platform.
I want every photo posted to have the same chance to appear in the news queue that's why I want them to appear randomly. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Users.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 30 } }])` or something simillar, depending on the library you are using should help

Answer (score 0):

add `sort` to `Users.find({}, function(err, result) {`
like this and put some field

```
Users.find({}, null, {sort: {date: 1,username:-1}}, function(err, result) { ... });
```

Comment: will you explain me a little ?